# Is it possible to turn _io.TextIOWrapper into a list?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, text

I have a dataframe and wanted to turn one of the columns into a list:

```
my_list = df_mydata['column2'].tolist()
```

The output is:

```
['This was the first row',
 'And the second'
 'I have some [parantheses]' 
 'that (might) play a role later']
```

However, `type(my_list)` is `_io.TextIOWrapper`. I wrote a code that iterates through the list items and there might be a problem in the data itself (because of the parentheses and because of using `re`, but that's another story), so I wanted to save this output as a text file, and obviously have it as a list. But the following code doesn't work because it says it's unreadable:

```
with open('my_list.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in my_list:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Can I just turn `my_list` into an actual list and then save it as `.txt` with the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try this and work correctly:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'column2': ['This was the first row',
                'And the second',
                'I have some [parantheses]' ,
                'that (might) play a role later']
})

my_list = df['column2'].tolist()

with open('my_list.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in my_list:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Comment: In your case type(my_list) is indeed a list, then my problem should be the dataframe itself? I tried type(df_mydata) and it says it is pandas.core.frame.DataFrame.

Comment: @johnnydoe is exactly this line `type(df_mydata['column2'].tolist())` output you  `_io.TextIOWrapper`?

Comment: the output of this line is list. I am very confused now haha

Comment: @johnnydoe did you run my code? this is working correctly.